# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation - when scrolling or moving in mapbox-gl map

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I working with Mapbox in Angular using

[ngx-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl)

with following versions:

```
ngx-mapbox-gl@3.0.1
mapbox-gl@0.52.0
```

By using a simple example just rendering a map I already get the following error fro **mapbox-gl.js:33**:

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation
```

Trace on scroll:

```
_o.onWheel  @   mapbox-gl.js:33
i.addEventListener.passive  @   mapbox-gl.js:33
push.../../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:421
push.../../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:188
push.../../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @   zone.js:496
invokeTask  @   zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback
```

trace on dragging the map:

```
    yo._onMove  @   mapbox-gl.js:33
push.../../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:421
push.../../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:188
push.../../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @   zone.js:496
invokeTask  @   zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback
```

I have tried to reproduce it on stackblitz but the same error is not thrown.

My chrome browser is on the latest version: Version 72.0.3626.119

I want to use mapbox to replace google maps. Such error is not thrown anywhere else in my app.

Appreciate any hint.